# How to add class to certain items in a loop php?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

Hi I'm fairly new to PHP and I'm have a problem adding a class to a group of three items in a loop. So basically I need items 1-3 int the loop to not have the class, items 4-6 to have the class, items 7-9 to not have the class, items 10-12 to not have the class and so on. I know I need to add a counter but I'm not sure how to write the if statement.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Sorry Here is an example of the code

```
global $wp_query;
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $wp_query->have_posts() ):
while( $wp_query->have_posts() ): $wp_query->the_post(); global $post; 

    echo '<article class="recipe">
        <div class="recipe-img"><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_post_thumbnail( $id, 'featured').'</a></div>
        <div class="recipe-info">
            <span>'.get_the_date().'</span> | <span>'.get_the_author().'</span>
            <a href="'.get_permalink().'">
                <h3 class="lato">'.get_the_title().'</h3>
            </a>
        </div>
    </article>';

}
endwhile;
    genesis_posts_nav();
endif;
```

I was able to do this but It only adds the class to every third item.

```
$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'recipes',
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'posts_per_page'=> '3',
            'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ),
        );
            global $wp_query;
            $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
            if( $wp_query->have_posts() ):
            $count = 0;
            while( $wp_query->have_posts() ): $wp_query->the_post(); global $post; 
            $count++;
            if ($count % 3 == 0 ) {

            echo '<article class="recipe third">
                <div class="recipe-img"><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_post_thumbnail( $id, 'featured').'</a></div>
                <div class="recipe-info">
                    <span>'.get_the_date().'</span> | <span>'.get_the_author().'</span>
                    <a href="'.get_permalink().'">
                        <h3 class="lato">'.get_the_title().'</h3>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </article>';

            } else {

            echo '<article class="recipe">
                <div class="recipe-img"><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_post_thumbnail( $id, 'featured').'</a></div>
                <div class="recipe-info">
                    <span>'.get_the_date().'</span> | <span>'.get_the_author().'</span>
                    <a href="'.get_permalink().'">
                        <h3 class="lato">'.get_the_title().'</h3>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </article>';

            }
            endwhile;
            genesis_posts_nav();
        endif;
```

Comment: oh wow, a code example is really very necessary. Even if you could write what you need in another language.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: @Iwnnay I have updated my question with a sample of the code.

Comment: There is some weird syntax as far as colons instead of `{`, but overlooking that I'm not seeing anything that explains the "class" items that you're looping over and intending to use your counter on. Every class is going to be a post. Maybe, an input and expected output is necessary to explain your situation. I'm kind of at a loss.

Comment: @Iwnnay I updated the question once again with an example I was able count every third item but not in groups of 3.

Answer (score 0):

Just add some extra control to your counter and alter your if statement a bit:

```
...
while( $wp_query->have_posts() ): $wp_query->the_post(); global $post;
    $count = $count > 6 ? 1 : $count + 1;
    if (($count > 3) && ($count <= 6) ) {
        echo(...);
...
```

Comment: Thanks @Codeartist! This almost works. On items 1-3 I don't get the class and items 4-6 I do get the class. That works perfectly but then I need to remove the class from posts 7-9. This code still leaves the class on 7-9.

Comment: I fixed it! All I needed to change was the `$count >= 6 ?`

Comment: Sorry, i was a bit confused by your description. I updated the answer. Now it work like that: 1-3 without class 4-6 with class then counter goes back to 1 & 7-9 got no class, 10-12 got the class. And so on. Anyway remember. It is counter. And it counts your posts. So try to play with if statement and keep in mind that when $counter reaches 7 it will be reset to 1 before your if  condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Counter Colors</title>
<style type="text/css">
    span{display: inline-block;padding: 10px;border:solid 1px #ccc;}
    .green{color: green;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
//phpinfo();

$class = 'class="green"';
$put_class = 1;

for ($i=1; $i <= 12 ; $i++) { 


    if($put_class == 1){
        echo '<span '.$class.'>'.$i.'</span>';
    } else{
        echo '<span>'.$i.'</span>';
    }

    if($i%3 == 0){
        if($put_class == 0){$put_class = 1;}
        else{$put_class = 0;}
    }

}
?>
</body>
</html>
```